# arrayformula + sumif to autofill / expanding result

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, sumifs

I want to do a simple SUMIF to return the total points for each player, but wanted to use ARRAYFORMULA to autofill down / give expanding results so when more players are added, the SUMIF doesn't need to be dragged down to the new rows.

I know ARRAYFORMULA doesn't work with SUMIFS, but I was sure it worked with SUMIF.

As you can see, the SUMIF is correctly bringing back the total points, but it's not expanding down the column.

Any advice? I was thinking maybe SUMPRODUCT but not sure where to go with that.

[image: screenshot of googledoc]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order for SUMIF to autofill within an arrayformula, the [criterion] parameter must be a range.

Change F2 to F2:F22.

Comment: It seems so obvious now you say it! Thank you.


Any thoughts on how to stop returning 0? I'm thinking iferror but it's not working:


=(arrayformula(iferror((IF(ROW(A:A)=1,"Score",sumif(A2:A22,F2:F22,D2:D22))))))

Comment: happy to help! To remove the zeros see the answer from @player0. Your formula is not working because the 0 is technically not an error, but it could be forced to become an error by dividing it by 1 and raising it to the power of negative 1 (`1/N^-1` or `1/(1/N)`, where `N` is the output of your SUMIF). This won't affect the final result because Sheets treats 1/(1/N) as N unless N is 0, in that case it returns an error and the IFERROR wrapper converts it to a blank value.

Answer (score 1):

use:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SUMIF(A2:A22, F2:F22, D2:D22))
```

for removing zeros use:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(1/(1/(SUMIF(A2:A22, F2:F22, D2:D22))))
```

---

with header:

```
={"Score"; ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(1/(1/(SUMIF(A2:A22, F2:F22, D2:D22))))}
```

Comment: Thank you, this works to remove the zeros :) I was using (IF(ROW(A:A)=1,"Score" to title the col but this stops working when I added your IFERROR - any thoughts how to include both?

Comment: @LucyJacksonOsborne sure. see the updated answer (3rd fx)

Comment: Thank you so much @player0 - really appreciate your help on this and my other question :)